# who is the prototype object of global object/scope in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, global-object

I tested this in Node shell:

```
var a = {}
a.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true

global.__proto__ === Object.prototype // false
global.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true

global.constructor.name // 'Object'
global.__proto__.constructor.name // 'Object'
```

My question:

1. why global object (global scope) 's prototype is NOT Object.prototype?
2. why global's constructor name displayed as 'Object' but it's prototype is not Object.prototype?

Comment: Where is `global` from? It's not in standard JavaScript; anyway - [environment] scopes do not have prototypes.

Comment: Do you realize that `global` is something that node.js makes up itself in its environment?  It's not a standard part of Javascript.  Your data makes it looks like it is an object inherited from Object.

Comment: @user2864740 I tested this code in both Node shell and SpiderMonkey's JS shell. The results are the same. Changing global to 'this' have the same output.

Comment: It's still something those two environments make up for their own use.

Answer (score 2):

If talking about [the Global Object](https://es5.github.io/#x15.1) which is *not* the same as [the Global Scope](https://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3) (although in the global scope `this === theGlobalObject`) the specification states:

> .. The values of the [[Prototype]] and [[Class]] internal properties of the global object *are implementation-dependent.*

To find an answer which is *specific* to Node.js, the implementation (or documentation on why such a decision was made) would need to be consulted. However there is *no* rationale/requirement provided by the specification.

Answer (score 0):

every object has an Object at the head of their prototype-chain right before null. The chain is as follows: `null->Object->A->B->C->D`

The reason `global.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true` works is because it follows null and then Object's prototype, which is the constructor for the new object. Global is the environment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Kind of, but not really how document and window are the superior-most structures in the DOM. I know that is a bad example, but it is the only js environment example I can think of at the moment.